# Force aspect ratio in media settings in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I am showing featured images of posts in a blog page, I'm using medium-size of media settings, but the images I upload doesn't have the same aspect ratio so when I resize my window to a different resolution they keep different heights and widths (I'm using bootstrap img-responsive). I want to know if I can't force an aspect ratio for all the images uploaded and resized to medium-size. I person that will upload the pictures don't have technical skills so he won't go to edit pics and change aspect ratio manually every time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question....sorry...ignore my answer.  What you really want is for the images to be cropped, not resized because if you change the ratio they will skewed. Is that correct?

Comment: but if you crop an image won't you lose a part of it?

Comment: I think it will work too if I can make all the pictures get the same heigt and width but in media settings only works with max-width not with width